# Field and Alternator Breakers

Tags: electrical-system

I under stand how the field and output breakers work within the electrical system. Monitoring the voltage output, I have a constant 13.5 volts at idle. During run up, the voltage will climb to ~13.8-14 volts while showing a constant +40 on the ammeter. Approaching 2000 rpm, the output and field will both pop at the same time. The battery has a resting voltage of 12 volts so I don't suspect a bad cell. I feel I should be looking for a short, but dont understand why both would pop at the same time unless the alternator itself is shorting.

Comment: If your output breaker is tripping, that is serious. It takes a load of something like 60 amps to trip. Stop messing around and get it repaired by a professional.

Comment: I 100% agree with @MikeSowsun, but if I were to take an educated guess, your voltage regulator has given up the ghost. Regardless, this is not an issue for self-troubleshooting unless you're already an A&P (which I suspect by the wording of the question that you are not.)